# Characteristic function of discrete distribution

Tags: probability-theory, self-learning

I want to calculate characteristic function of following discrete distribution:
$$P(X=m)=\frac{a^{m}}{(a+1)^{m+1}}$$

where $m=0,1,2......$ and  $a>0$.

$$\varphi _{X}(t)=\frac{e^{it}}{(a+1)}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{(ae)^{m}}{(a+1)^{m}}$$

I tried to reduce it to sum of geometric series, but I am stuck at this point.

Comment: But your last series **is** the sum of a geometric series... whose argument should read $\frac{ae^{it}}{a+1}$ instead of $\frac{ae}{a+1}$.

Comment: Thanks, but I dont know how to prove that $ae^{it}<a+1$ so that ($q<1$)

Comment: $|e^{it}|=1$, you can see it as $|\cos t +i\sin t|$

Comment: Actually, you only need $|ae^{it}|<|a+1|$, which holds for every $a>0$ (and note that $ae^{it}<a+1$ would assume an order relation $<$ on $\mathbb C$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking Did's comment, let's demonstrate that $\left|\dfrac {ae^{it}}{a+1}\right|\lt1$.

$|ae^{it}|=|a|\cdot |e^{it}|=|a|\cdot|\cos(t)+i\sin(t)|=|a|\sqrt{\cos^2(t)+\sin^2(t)}=|a|$

Thus $\left|\dfrac {ae^{it}}{a+1}\right|=\left|\dfrac a{a+1}\right|=\dfrac a{a+1}\lt1$